# Visual Studio Python Kivy Unknown Directive Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently trying to run a basic kivy script in Visual Studio Code, but everytime I run the .kv file, I get an 'Unknown directive' error in the terminal. I have installed the Kivy Extension by Battle Bas and installed kivy on my device via the kivy website, however the error still persists.

**This is My Python Script:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**And This is my Kivy Script in the .kv file:**

```
#:kivy2.0.0
<MyGrid>
   Label:
       text: "Hello!"
```

---

**This is What it Says in My Terminal:**

```
     raise ParserException(self, ln, 'Unknown directive')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "c:\Users\hasan\kivy-Tutorial ver2\my.kv", line 1:
 ...
 >>    1:#:kivy2.0.0
       2:<MyGrid>
       3:    Label:
 ...
 Unknown directive
```

I would really appreciate it if someone would help because this is my first time using Stack Overflow and I really want to build apps with Python. Thank You!

Comment: Did you manage to find any examples of Kivy scripts by searching the Internet? Do they look like yours? How about if you put `kivy unknown directive` into a search engine? Do you get results that help you solve the problem?

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel,
Yeah, I tried to find similar issues, however many had no answers to them or replies (and didn't help) so I decided to ask on Stack Overflow myself and see if anyone has a solution to my particular issue. From what I've noticed from researching, Kivy errors on VScode is a common issue, but the ones that I looked at didn't really match the issue I was having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file):

> The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header,
> where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re
> using. For now, use 1.0:
>
> #:kivy 1.0

Note that the header is `#:kivy`  followed by a space then the string version.

Try changing your header from:

```
#:kivy2.0.0
```

to

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
```

Comment: Thank you!! This actually worked! You helped me find out that I had to add the space and I also found out that I had to save the file as well for the output to display properly. I honestly take this answer as a lesson that even something as small as a space can make a huge difference to the way your code will run. THANKS!!! Also, by the way, is there an auto-saver extension in VScode? It would be helpful since I have to always save the file before I run the kivy script in order for it to give the intended output. Again, Thank You!!

Comment: Can't help you with Visual Studio as I use PyCharm, which automatically saves whenever I hit `run`.